# Search within the contributions of a specific editor

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

On Wikipedia (and MediaWiki in general), is there any way to search for a phrase within the contributions of a specific user? As a proof-of-concept, I want to find a way to search for the word "Wikipedia" within the contributions of the user "Jimbo Wales": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/Jimbo_Wales

Comment: I hope it's possible to use a tool like WikiBlame for this purpose (but this doesn't appear to be its intended use).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a tool available to easily retrieve the information you need, but I strongly recommend that you [download a copy](http://dumps.wikimedia.org) of the database and analyse the contributions of the specific user that you need.

Alternatively, you can query the database directly using the Wikimedia Toolserver (if on Wikimedia projects) or the master server database the wiki is on, using the conditions of the user_id and page content to search.

Can't really help much, but there really isn't such a tool currently available.